# How to change the color and icon of listview item on click when using SlidingMenu library?

Tags: android, listview, slidingmenu

I am using SlidingMenu library for creating side menu in my project.I need to change the background color and icon of my selected side menu item when it is clicked.How to do this?

This is the class where i set listview items in side menu.

```
public class SampleListFragment extends ListFragment {
public String[] menus = { "Home","Offers", "History", "Profile"};

public Integer[] icons = { R.drawable.icon_a,R.drawable.icon_b,
        R.drawable.icon_c,R.drawable.d};

MainActivity fca;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    fca = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());

    for (int i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
        adapter.add(new SampleItem(menus[i], icons[i]));
    }
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Fragment newContent = null;

    switch (position) {
    case 0:

        newContent = new HomeFragment();

        break;

    case 1:

        newContent = new OffersFragment();

        break;

    case 2:
        newContent = new HistoryFragment();

        break;

    case 3:
        newContent = new ProfileFragment();

        break;

    }
    if (newContent != null)
        switchFragment(newContent);
}

private class SampleItem {
    public String tag;
    public int iconRes;

    public SampleItem(String tag, int iconRes) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.iconRes = iconRes;
    }
}

private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (getActivity() == null)
        return;

    if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {

        fca.switchContent(fragment);

    }

}

public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {

    public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,
                    null);
        }
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
        icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).iconRes);
        final TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_title);


        title.setText(getItem(position).tag);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: if i am not getting you wrong then you just want to highlight the selected list item of slide menu. why don't you just use selector for list items ?

Comment: I used selector.Its working.But I need to change my icons also.

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- default -->
  </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add list-selector in listview.

   android:listSelector
2. Create a selecter in drawable folder list_selecter.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/red_light" />
</selector>`

3. set list-selector in listview

   android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selecter"

Comment: How to change the icons??

Comment: also use selector for icon drawable,  when selected specify different icon